# Adjusting the arguments of WooCommerce add-to-cart shortcode not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, shortcode, wordpress-shortcode

I'm trying to use Woocommerce shortcode on a random page to create an "Add to Cart" button. I don't want the price to show and I don't want the default grey border. I figured I should make the shortcode as such: 
`[add_to_cart id="34022" style="0" show_price="FALSE"]`

But the added arguments are somehow not being taken into account. It stays exactly the same as if I would have put only this:

`[add_to_cart id="34022"]`

I tried also using other inline styles than "0" but nothing I do makes a difference. I don't understand what I am doing wrong... It doesn't seem to respond at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
[add_to_cart id="34022" style=" " show_price="false"]
```

Try this shortcode

These are the available attributes with defaults.

```
    $atts = shortcode_atts(
        array(
            'id'         => '',
            'class'      => '',
            'quantity'   => '1',
            'sku'        => '',
            'style'      => 'border:4px solid #ccc; padding: 12px;',
            'show_price' => 'true',
        ),
        $atts,
        'product_add_to_cart'
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I totally lost track of this post. I tried it now but it did not change anything. Would it be possible to override those default styles somewhere?